# how to break design into pieces after x loops

Tags: php, arrays, loops, foreach

I have a loop which I want to take this behaver

first to add item div then loop into this div to add 6 items And after complete 6 items it will close this div and start again with next six items until finish

my current code like this :

```
        <?php $x = 0; ?>
      <?php  foreach ($files as $lst) { ?>
        <div class="item <?= ($x == 1 ? 'active' : ''); ?>">
            <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-2">
                    <a href="<?= base_url() ?>global/uploads/<?= $lst['FileName'] ?>"
                       rel="prettyPhoto[gallery1]">
                        <?php if ($lst['FileName'] != "" && file_exists(PUBPATH . "global/uploads/" . $lst['FileName'])) { ?>
                            <img src="<?= thumb($lst['FileName'], 150, 150); ?>" class="img-responsive">
                        <?php } else { ?>
                            <img src="<?= base_url() ?>global/site/data/1.jpg" class="img-responsive">
                        <?php } ?>
                    </a>
                </div>
            </div>
            </div>
            <?php $x++;
        } ?>
```

but i want final structure to be like this

```
        <div class="item active">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-2">
                    <a href="#"><img src="data/1.jpg" class="img-responsive"></a>
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-2">
                    <a href="#"><img src="data/1.jpg" class="img-responsive"></a>
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-2">
                    <a href="#"><img src="data/1.jpg" class="img-responsive"></a>
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-2">
                    <a href="#"><img src="data/1.jpg" class="img-responsive"></a>
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-2">
                    <a href="#"><img src="data/1.jpg" class="img-responsive"></a>
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-2">
                    <a href="#"><img src="data/1.jpg" class="img-responsive"></a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-2">
                    <a href="#"><img src="data/1.jpg" class="img-responsive"></a>
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-2">
                    <a href="#"><img src="data/1.jpg" class="img-responsive"></a>
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-2">
                    <a href="#"><img src="data/1.jpg" class="img-responsive"></a>
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-2">
                    <a href="#"><img src="data/1.jpg" class="img-responsive"></a>
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-2">
                    <a href="#"><img src="data/1.jpg" class="img-responsive"></a>
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-2">
                    <a href="#"><img src="data/1.jpg" class="img-responsive"></a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You should clean the code a bit, instead of filtering inside the loop the array should contain the files and urls you want to enlist.

That would separate HTML from your PHP code making it much easier to read.

```
$files = [
  'data/1.jpg', // can make an array as well, ['src'=>'data/1.jpg', 'href => 'link.com']
  'data/2.jpg',
  'data/3.jpg',
  'data/4.jpg',
  'data/5.jpg',
  'data/6.jpg',
  'data/7.jpg',
];

foreach(array_chunk($files, 6) as $row){
  echo '<div class="item"><div class="row">';
  foreach($row as $col){
    echo '<div class="col-xs-2">';
    echo '<a href="#"><img src="'.$col.'" class="img-responsive"></a>';
  //echo '<a href="'.$col['href'].'"><img src="'.$col['src'].'" class="img-responsive"></a>';
    echo '</div>';
  }
  echo '</div></div>';
}
```